# Bash sort lines starting with punctuation in non-dictionary order

Tags: bash, sort, coreutils

I have a file containing lines, some of which start with a `!` character, some with a `?` character, and some with a space ( ) character. The second character is always a letter of the alphabet.

When I try to use the bash `sort` command from coreutils, this seems to ignore the the first character, and sort according to the second only.

This surprised me very much, as I assumed the sort would treat the punctuation numbers by their ascii value, and lump all the `!` lines together, followed by all the `?` lines together, etc.

In particular, the documentation says there's a `-d` option, which explicitly instructs the `sort` command to ignore such punctuation marks. But what I want is the opposite behaviour, and there's no option to 'reverse' this behaviour. It's as if the `-d` option has been "baked in" somehow.

I have checked, and as far as I know, I don't have an alias defined somewhere that might activate the `-d` flag by accident.

Is this a bug in `sort`? (coreutils v8.32). Is there a way to force it NOT to sort by dictionary order but by strict ascii value?

<sub>OS: Linux Mint 21.1 (based on ubuntu jammy, afaik) in case this is relevant</sub>

EDIT: Providing locale and MVP as requested

```
$ locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

```
$ echo '
> !a
> ?b
>  c
> !f
>  e
> ?d' | sort 

!a
?b
 c
?d
 e
!f
```

Comment: What's your locale setting? Can you post a sample of the input?

Comment: @choroba done. see edited question. (the `>` characters denote line continuation input in the terminal)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to sort in the `C` locale. Ex. given

```
$ printf '%2s\n' '!a' '?b' 'c' '!f' 'e' '?d'
!a
?b
 c
!f
 e
?d
```

then

```
$ printf '%2s\n' '!a' '?b' 'c' '!f' 'e' '?d' | LC_COLLATE=C sort
 c
 e
!a
!f
?b
?d
```

or perhaps better, use `LC_ALL=C` since according to `info sort` the former is affected by other variables:

> ---------- Footnotes ----------
>
> (1) If you use a non-POSIX locale (e.g., by setting ‘LC_ALL’ to
> ‘en_US’), then ‘sort’ may produce output that is sorted differently
> than you’re accustomed to.  In that case, set the ‘LC_ALL’ environment
> variable to ‘C’.  Note that setting only ‘LC_COLLATE’ has two
> problems. First, it is ineffective if ‘LC_ALL’ is also set.  Second,
> it has undefined behavior if ‘LC_CTYPE’ (or ‘LANG’, if ‘LC_CTYPE’ is
> unset) is set to an incompatible value.  For example, you get
> undefined behavior if ‘LC_CTYPE’ is ‘ja_JP.PCK’ but ‘LC_COLLATE’ is
> ‘en_US.UTF-8’.

Comment: That's great, thanks! This "solves" the problem, though if you could explain a bit more why this discrepancy between en_GB vs C exists, or why the LC_COLLATE variable is the relevant one to override in this case and what it does exactly, that would be great! Also, your solution seems to break the `-d` switch in an equally interesting way ... but I guess that's a question for another day. :)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou tbh I don't understand locales sufficiently to answer with confidence - I *think* the short answer is that punctuation is ignored (or more precisely, is assigned equal collation weight) in non-ASCII locales - see for example [strange behavior of sort](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/577256/65304). I may even be wrong about which variable to set (`info sort` says to use `LC_ALL` not `LC_COLLATE` since the latter is affected by other variables).

Comment: Thank you. The linked answer was very useful in understanding what collation order is, and makes the above behaviour slightly less cryptic (locales are such a mess though...)